# How to set a file name using window.open

Tags: javascript, download, window.open

I'am trying to download temporary result calculated by JavaScript. Say I have a string `str`, I want to download a file contains `str` and named it as `data.csv`, I'm using the following code:

```
window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + str);
```

The file can be successfully downloaded, but how can I name the file `data.csv` automatically rather than set the name by hand each time?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `download` attribute for `<a>` elements. For example:

```
<a href="1251354216241621.txt" download="your-foo.txt">Download Your Foo</a>
```

This attribute indicates that the file should be downloaded (instead of displayed, if applicable) and specifies which filename should be used for the downloaded file.

Instead of using `window.open()` you could generate an invisible link with the `download` attribute and `.click()` it.

```
var str = "Name, Price\nApple, 2\nOrange, 3";
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + str;

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = uri;
downloadLink.download = "data.csv";

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

Unfortunately this isn't supported in all browsers, but adding it won't make things worse for other browsers: they'll continue to download the files with useless filenames. *(This assumes that you're using a MIME type is that their browser attempts to download. If you're trying to let the user download an `.html` file instead of displaying it, this won't do you any good in unsupported browsers.)*

Comment: The `downloadLink.click();` part in Google Chrome 58.0.3029.110 doesn't start download. I manually have to click the hyperlink to do so. Any workarounds or is it unsupported in the specified browser.

Comment: You do not have to append this element to body. Just invoke `.click()` and that's all!

Comment: @AchmedzianovDanilian I had to append the link to make it work in Firefox 59. Without it in the DOM, the click() appears to do nothing.

Comment: @ManoDestra, you're absolutely right. Just checked, this.

Comment: Is it can just open without download??

Comment: downloadLink.click() is not working for me on Safari with ics file. Safari does not open the file automatically. Use window.open and it works but the file name is uknown.

Answer (score 28):

That does not work in latest Chrome, I have modified that and the following code will work fine,

```
 $("#download_1").on('click', function() {
    var json_pre = '[{"Id":1,"UserName":"Sam Smith"},{"Id":2,"UserName":"Fred Frankly"},{"Id":1,"UserName":"Zachary Zupers"}]';
    var json = $.parseJSON(json_pre);
   
    var csv = JSON2CSV(json);
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csv]);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.href = url;
    downloadLink.download = "data.csv";

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
});
```

So when you click on download_1 id button then it will create an invisible download link and click that. I have used another function to prepare js.

The JSON2CSV function is as follows:

```
function JSON2CSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    var line = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';

        for (var index in array[i]) {
           line += array[i][index] + ',';
        }

        line = line.slice(0, -1);
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
}
```

Hope it will help others :)

Comment: what part? it worked for me in chrome for download the file with the right name

Comment: Perfectly downloads the CSV file! Could you please help on how to include the keys (Id, Username) as well?

Answer (score 19):

A shorter version of accepted one *(for my case had to use unicode)*

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = 'data:text/csv,' + encodeURIComponent("algún texto");
link.download = "Example.csv";
link.click();
```

Comment: Is it can just open without download??

Comment: for me it's opened. try and let me know.

Comment: Not for me. It starts to download.
Safari, Chrome in MacOS.

Comment: I think it's a browser setting. you can set it to open or download.

Answer (score 10):

A solution for IE is to use msSaveBlob and pass the file name.

For modern browsers solution goes like this, tested: IE11, FF & Chrome

```js
 var csvData = new Blob([arg.data], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
        //IE11 & Edge
        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            navigator.msSaveBlob(csvData, exportFilename);
        } else {
            //In FF link must be added to DOM to be clicked
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
            link.setAttribute('download', exportFilename);
            document.body.appendChild(link);    
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);    
        }
```

There is a good discution about that [here](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/175)