# Issue on Exporting HTML Table To Ms Excel in Mac Computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel

I am trying to export an HTML Table to Ms Excel Using [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/xhYcD/) but it is exporting a file called "download" (without  excel file extensions)and when I double click on that it opens like a text file.
Can you please let me know why this is happening?

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Most likely because your "download" button is inside your "dvData" `div`.  Move your download button outside that `div`.

Comment: Thanks dave I moved the button on the top page before the div element but still gettong a file with no extension!

Comment: For the filename you are at the mercy of the browser. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034754/how-to-set-a-file-name-using-window-open) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)