# Download CSV Via AJAX Post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csv

Hi there Stackoverflow. I am trying to call a PHP script via AJAX that will create and download a CSV file. I know this isn't normally supposed to be done, however I would like to do it this way.

My ajax below returns the csv data as shown by this output:

[image]

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=site_url('front_office/get_csv/')?>",
    data: {hashed_center_ids : hashed_center_ids, print_data : print_data},
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(response);
        window.open(uri, 'test.csv');
    }
});
```

The problem is that using the lines

`var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(response);
window.open(uri, 'test.csv');`

does not download the file as a CSV. But rather it give it no extension with the name "download". Does anybody know how can I make it so it downloads with the .csv extension? Thanks.

Comment: Let me get this right, you want to post some data to a PHP, that will process it and return a CSV data? And you want that returned data to be automatically offered as a file download?

Comment: If that is the case you should read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034754/how-to-set-a-file-name-using-window-open

Comment: `application/csv` isn't a valid mime type. The correct mime type for a csv is `text/csv`

Comment: It works Mark. Any idea how to change the name? It comes out as "download.csv".

Comment: That is correct Emil.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so: You can change the name of the csv by adding following to the header

```
 filename=whatever.csv
```