# Specify file name when printing page element using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, document.write

I need to specify a filename when printing a page element using javascript.

Here is my code that will print the specified `elementId` from the page:

```
function printPartOfPage(elementId) {   
var printHeader = document.getElementById('header');
var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
var windowUrl = 'NewWindow';
var uniqueName = new Date();
var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=20,top=200');
printWindow.document.write('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>');    
printWindow.document.write('<link href='+sURL+'css/style.css rel="stylesheet">');   
printWindow.document.write('<link href='+sURL+'css/print.css rel="stylesheet">');   
printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');    
printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();
setTimeout(function(){
    printWindow.print();
}, 500)
printWindow.setTimeout("window.close()", 2000);
}
```

This works fine, except that the default file name that appears in the print dialog is `download.pdf` and I need to specify my own file name based on parameters from the url:

https://example.com/a/b/c/123456789/2019/1

I would like to construct a file name using the **last three elements** of the URL such that the default file name that appears in the print dialog window is:

`123456789_2019_1.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How to set a file name using window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034754/how-to-set-a-file-name-using-window-open)

Seems to be a work around, but a good one.