# Give a name to ICS file with jQuery and opening this one on the fly

Tags: cross-browser, filenames, icalendar

My ICS script work fine but depending on the browser his behavior is different!

First issue :

Browsers generate these file names =
Safari : Unknown-1.ics
GG Chrome, brave : téléchargement(1).ics
Edge : télécharger (1).ics
Firefox : 1YV-GiAT.ics

How to do to allocate a name do ICS file to have for example "my-special-event.ics" ?

Strangely the file is displayed in a different way between the download folder and the recent files folder on MacOs

[image] [image] .

I will test on windows system next time to see how it display.

Is there a way to generate (only with Jquery) a "download link" () which would contain the ICS link ?

Second issue (On MacOS):

For the same ICS script, the data/calendar link open on the fly only with safari Browser .
For all other it is necessary to double click on ICS file inside download folder to add event to calendar.

Is there a way to always (each browser on macOS) open ICS file on the fly ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found a solution to name the .ics file. Didn't find an specific answer for .ics files, so here is an answer for someone still looking for a solution to this question (this at least works on chrome and firefox, haven't tested it on other browsers).

Found the solution on this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034754/how-to-set-a-file-name-using-window-open)

In the selected answer Jeremy explains that you should use an invisible link/anchor. That way you can name the .ics file. In my case it meant this (I used ajax to create an .ics formatted string):

```
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape([.ics formatted string]);

var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = uri;
downloadLink.download = 'yourfilename.ics'; //<=== Set here your file name
downloadLink.style = 'display: none;';

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

Hopefully it helps!